# Undefined parameter in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to rewrite an AJAX request of mine so I can debug it's responses, so I have moved code from the responses into individual functions. In my original code I was able to get the result returning from the AJAX call, and output it in the success response.

Since moving that code into a separate function and then trying to call that function in the success response, I get the error 'result is undefined'. I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to know why this is happening, please help.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/auth/api/Homepage/GetLinks',
  success:displayLinks(result, jqStatus, error),
  error: showPolicyLinkError(result, jqStatus, error)
});

function displayLinks(result, jqStatus, error){
    $('#numbercontrol').html(result);
    console.log("Success Log - Satus:" + jqStatus + " Error:" + error);
}

function showLinkError(result, jqStatus, error){
    $('#numbercontrol').html("<p>Unable to return any links.</p>");
    console.log("Failure Log - Result: " + result + "Satus:" + jqStatus + " Error:" + error);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only pass function names without arguments:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/auth/api/Homepage/GetLinks',
    success: displayLinks,
    error: showLinkError
});
```